# UIImage getting clipped from side when put in UITableViewCell

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage

[image: icon image clipping]

The icon visible in the page is getting clipped whenever launched in portrait mode specially in non-retina devices. I had tried putting a UIView behind UIImageView and adjusting the struts and springs of that View but in vain.

i had tried :
UIImage *stretchableIconImage = [iconImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 1, 0, 0)];
but this doesn't works. The UITableViewCell has its own cellrow image (alternate white and grey).
How can I avoid the clipping of the icon?

Comment: Give absolutely everything a background color. Honestly, do that and your problem will be very easy to find.

Comment: by easy to find u mean u can't detect the clipping in the image or I will be able to find the problem?